VBA MS Word - Delete all headers not footers
I am facing an issue where I am trying to delete all the headers, but I am deleting the footers as well. I am using WDHeaderFooterPrimary, but the footer is still being deleted. I have moved all the sections to the end of the page for future work on the document.
     ' remove all sections
    For i = doc.Sections.Count To 5 Step -1
          With doc.Sections(i).Range.Find
               .ClearFormatting
               .Text = "^b"
               .Replacement.ClearFormatting
               .Replacement.Text = ""
               .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
          End With
    Next

     'insert section after each page
     For i = 5 To doc.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
          Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToLast, Count:=i
          Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous
     Next
     
     ' delete shapes
     For i = 5 To doc.Sections.Count
          Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToFirst, Count:=i
          Set hdr = doc.Sections(i).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
               For Each shp In hdr.Shapes
                    shp.Delete
               Next
     Next

How do I remove just the headers?

For example:
Sub DeleteAllHeaders()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Sctn As Section, HdFt As HeaderFooter
For Each Sctn In ActiveDocument.Sections
  For Each HdFt In Sctn.Headers
    If HdFt.Exists Then HdFt.Range.Text = vbNullString
  Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

